# sns.regplot cambio de color utilizando hue

Tags: python, seaborn

Hola a todas las personas de la comunidad, quisiera saber si en un gráfico de dispersión se puede cambiar de color los puntos del gráfico dependiendo de un valor, en otra clase de gráficos, como los diagramas de caja estaba usando "hue" pero en este otro gráfico da error.

```
sns.regplot(x="CWDistance", y="Wingspan",hue="Gender",data=df,fit_reg=False , 
scatter_kws={"alpha":0.3})
```

El error que me sale es por el hue, se indica:

TypeError: regplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hue'

Sin este argumento si sirve el gráfico, pero me gustaría saber como puedo diferenciar por género en este caso los puntos. Gracias.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema y es un ejercicio guiado en donde me piden claramente que solamente agregue esta línea al argumento de la función "hue=df['Gender']".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Podrías utilizar [`seaborn.lmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) que también es de dispersión pero soporta el argumento `hue`

Como no incluiste los datos de tu `dataframe` cree un ejemplo sencillo con un dataset de seaborn

Esta es la gráfica con `regplot`:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(color_codes=True)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.regplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
```

Esto crea la siguiente gráfica:

[image: Gráfica con regplot]

Y esta es con `lmplot`

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(color_codes=True)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips, hue='smoker')
```

Esto crea la siguiente gráfica:

[image: Gráfica con lmplot]